# Format of MatLab Integration Result

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to integrate a function with matlab but it keeps giving me strange
results.

```
>> syms w x;
>> w = 0.8335*(cosh(52.42*x)-cos(52.42*x)-sinh(52.42*x)+sin(52.42*x));
>> int(w, 0, 1)
>> (1667*sinh(2621/50))/104840 ... /*Some long expression*/
```

Instead of giving me some final numerical value it leaves the integration with `sinh(2621/50)`. Am I using the wrong functions? Any help would be great.

Comment: Note that numerical integration for 'nice' functions is really easy in matlab, just define `x = 0:0.000001:1;` then calculate `w` and take the `mean`. In your case i would say it is about  0.0427.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the numerical value you can just evaluate the resulting expression.
Note that sinh(2621/50) is just a number.

Comment: I can do that but is there any way that I can avoid that. I want matlab to give me direct final result (something like 131.12)

Comment: Not sure but how about wrapping your `int` with an eval or multiplying it with 1?

Comment: eval seems to work...although I was expecting some change in my parameters. anyway thank for help

Answer (score -1):

I do not have access to the symbolic toolbox, but if you want precise control of the output it seems like the function `vpa()` ([mathworks variable-precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/vpa.html)) is an alternative to evaluating the expression.

For example `vpa(int(w, 0, 1),5)` would give you 5 significant digits.

Comment: This still calls `int` and requires the definition of `w`, after checking the doc it seems like this is just part of the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I see that I perhaps was a bit unclear. Yes, it is a symbolic toolbox function and yes, it evaluates the expression `int()` just as you would have to do when you evaluate the resulting expression. The question was if it was possible to get a numerical result from `int()`. It does not seem like this is possible. Using `vpa()` on the resulting expression only makes it possible to control the number of significant digits. (It seems like this function more commonly is used to get a numerical approximation of the result when an analytical result can not be found.)